# How to use UITextField UIAppearance based on user Interaction enabled trait

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to find a way to have UITextField appearance is distinguishable when user interaction is disabled. I have to do this application wide. Thought using UIAppearance could be an easy way to do. But couldn't figure out how to use that with user interaction enabled trait of text field.

Can you help? Or Is there an alternate way to do the same thing centrally.

Note: Text field user interaction enabled state on a given instance can get toggled based on user action.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an app wide way to do it if you're using text fields directly, but if you were to subclass `UITextField` and override `setEnabled:`, you could make a change to the background there.

```
@implementation MYTextField

- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

@end
```

There is already a faint grey background for `UITextField`s which are disabled, but if this is not enough you can do more as above. Alternatively, you could use `setDisabledBackground:` on each `UITextField` to set an image for display when disabled - I accept that this isn't a great solution with the current design paradigms.